# Restore NSUserDefaults from iTunes sync

Tags: iphone, itunes, nsuserdefaults, synchronization

Is it possible to restore `NSUserDefaults` from the latest iTunes backup even after the App is deleted from the device?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. If you have values saved in the user defaults, those values will get backed up during iTunes backup. If your device is restored from backup, the values saved there will be restored.

You would need to restore from the backup to the entire device. Restoring just 1 app won't suffice. Hope this helps.